# how to fetch all chatroom of logged users with stream query in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

image showing my data structure,

I have created a chatroom collection,

a chatroom collection has some field like id, last message and a map which key is chat members userid and bool for indicating blocked by,

now here I want to fetch all chat room that belongs to logged user,

I got following suggestion

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('chatrooms')
                  .where("participants."+widget.user.userid.toString(),isEqualTo: true,
                     )
                  .snapshots(),
```

but here I don't want to compare with bool value as I want all chatroom belongs to logged user whether it is blocked or not...

**How to write stream query for checking, has map any key that is equal to logged userid.**

Actually I have taken this example to learn more and more about firebase but stuck in first attempt of query

Explaining:
participants are the member of chat room users and given their id as key of participant field and bool for checking if anyone has blocked or not....

what I wanted to do further

1. to fetch all chatroom that contains logged user 's id in participants map...(to view all logged user's chat room)
2. to fetch all chatroom that is blocked by logged user
3. to fetch all chatroom that is blocked by target user(second user)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Firestore doesn't allow querying nested values. One way you could get aroud that is to keep an array of currently active users. Then you would a query that checks if user id is in that array.

Comment: If firebase not allowing query nested than how to solve....this one is simple example and I am stuck...there can be more complex data...than how to deal with it..